# rewrite URL with query parameters in path

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, config

So I need to rewrite:

```
mysite.com/page?type=2
```

to:

```
mysite.com/page/type/2
```

but not affect url's like:

```
mysite.com/page/type/2
```

I have tried using:

```
rewrite ^/page?.*$ /page/type/$arg_type? permanent;
```

but for some reason this is catching and rewriting the last case (where I don't want the url rewritten) in a loop. I wouldn't think it would get caught in a redirect loop due to the question mark exempting it, but maybe I don't fully understand the syntax...

Thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^/page/?$ /page/type/$arg_type? permanent;
```